# Mongodb and Express deleting an item from _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js, crud

I'm new to Express and databases. I'm trying to create a simple CRUD todo list by following several tutorials using Mongo DB (not Mongoose), Express, Node, and Handlebars.

I can create items from an input form and have them successfully save to the Mongo database and the page. I can't figure out how to delete each item based on a button click both on the page and from the database. Ideally, I want to target them based on the `_id` that Mongo creates.

I think the issue might be having something to do with the way I'm trying to select each item. Any suggestions or easier ways to implement this would be great!

Here is my code for Express:

```
// Connecting Mongo DB
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = client.db('todoitems')
})

 // Save items to DB from form
app.post('/items', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('items').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(req.body, {_id: req.body._id})
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})

// Delete item on click from DB
app.delete('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('items').remove({_id: req.body.id}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})

// Get items from DB to page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('items').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('index', {
      layout: false,
      items: result
    });
  })
})
```

And here is my code from the Handlebars file:

```
  <form action="/items" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="item" name="item">
    <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date" value="CurrentDate">
  </form>

  <ul>
    {{#each items}}
      <li>
        <span>{{item}} |</span>
        <span>{{date}}</span>
        <button id={{_id}}>x</button>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are removing by `_id`, you need to pass an `ObjectID(id)` not a "string" `id`, something like:

```
remove({_id: mongodb.ObjectID( req.params.id)} ...
```

So, your code should be like:

```
app.delete('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('items').remove({_id: mongodb.ObjectID( req.params.id)}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to use ObjectID but I'm still not certain how to remove the record on click from Mongo. Do I need to listen for an event or should I attach the `id={{_id}}` from Handlebars on the entire record? I'm fuzzy on how they connect.

Comment: To add on the above answer, instead of a `DELETE` request method, convert that to a `GET` and use a link instead of a button to fire that request i.e. instead of `app.delete('/items/:id', (req, res) => {` do `app.get('/items/delete/:id', (req, res) => { ... }` and replace `<button id={{_id}}>x</button>` with `<a href="/items/delete/{{_id}}">x</a>`

Comment: You should try to split your problem in smaller pieces, try my solution with [curl](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/curl-command-examples/), in your case you, for a delete, you need something like: `curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/items/id"`. After you have the delete working, focus on the Handlebars issue

Comment: Thanks for both of these ideas. I'm going to break it into pieces and try and get it working.